# How can I set the Mac OS X terminal history to act like linux when using up/down arrows?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I'd like for the mac os terminal app to scroll through my command history the same way that it work in linux, if possible. Currently, if I push the up arrow in the terminal, it will scroll through **each and every one** of my recent commands **even if the last 50 were the same exact command**. On most linux systems I've used, this behavior will scroll backwards through command history, but most importanlty it will **skip duplicate commands**. Is this behavior possible in Mac OS X terminal app, or do I need to use a different terminal app? Thanks.

Comment: This is not the action of the Terminal app but how you have set up your shell - probably bash see its documentation for history

Comment: Also check out iTerm2.  IMO it's a better tool.  http://www.iterm2.com

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mark who commented on my questions above was correct. This is a bash setting. If you add the following to your `~/.bashrc` script, you will get this behavior.

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
```

You can also ignore any lines that start with a space:

```
HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
```

Or do both, by using:

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
```

Comment: Strictly better add to  .bashrc and make .bash_profile source .bashrc - see bash manual

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are using bash then

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
```

or

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
```

in one of your bash rc file(s).